# XPath: Select child based on siblings where there are 'twins'

Tags: xml, xpath, siblings

I just can't quite figure this out. So I have the following XML:

```
<config>
<environment>
    <loc>eu</loc>
    <url>something</url>
</environment>
<environment>
    <loc>au</loc>
    <loc>ap</loc>
    <url>somethingElse</url>
</environment>
```

I want to get the `<url>` element based on a given `<loc>`.

I've got the following XPath which works if I want the `<url>` for **eu** but does not work for if I want it for **ap**.

**Works (returns 'something')**

```
/config/environment[loc="eu"]/url
```

**Does not Work (returns nothing, expecting 'somethingElse')**

```
/config/environment[loc="ap"]/url
```

I know `/config/environment[loc[1]="ap"]/url` will work but I could have any number of `<loc>` elements so I don't want my XPath to be so static / dependent on position.

Any help to come up with, what I assume is a simple tweak, so I can get the `<url>` regardless of the order of `<loc>` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/config/environment[loc="ap"]/url` should've worked. How did you run the xpath? What is the environment? it returned `somethingElse` for me, at least [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: actually you're right @har07. I was trying to do this in VBA (using MSXML v4.0) but if I change my reference to MSXML v6.0, then my original XPath does actually work. Perhaps a different version of XPath?

Comment: I really suspect you just need to do: `dom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"`. Seems that xpath isn't the default selection language in older MSXML. : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/config/environment/loc[text() = 'eu']/following-sibling::url
```

or this:

```
/config/environment/loc[text() = 'eu']/following-sibling::url[1]
```

Comment: `<url>` is child of `<environment>` not sibling

Comment: Thx @har07 forgot to add the loc